# Updating wrong values in database when two form submit same time by two user

Tags: php

Hello and thanks for looking my codes!

Well i am facing problem when two form submit by two user same time. I will try to elaborate it.

My form has to update three user values,

**My php:**

```
<?php
set_time_limit(60);
if (isset($_POST['submit-buy'])) {
    $buy_id = $_POST['buy_id'];
    $buyer_id = $_POST['buyer_id']; 
    $buy_value = $_POST['buy_value'];
    $owner_id = $_POST['owner_id']; 

    // more function goes here and returns value below i am also using if else to check if any value change it gives error msg to slow down
    // $petvalue = 100000;
    // $pet_earn = 5500;
    // $check_petcash = 10000000;
    // $pet_newvalue = 110000;
    // $pet_updateoid = 1;
    // $pettobuy = 2;

    // first

    $check_petcash = $pet_user->cash;    //checking before updating
    $pet_newcash = round($check_petcash + $pet_earn);            // pet new cash        
    $upet_newvalue = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET value='$pet_newvalue', cash='$pet_newcash', ownerid='$pet_updateoid' WHERE id='$pettobuy'");       

    // second
    // $old_owner = 3;

    $ex_owner_cash = $oldowner->cash;    //checking before updating     
    $ex_owner_newcash = round($ex_owner_cash + $petvalue + $pet_earn);  // old owner cash               
    $update_newcash = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET cash='$ex_owner_newcash' WHERE id='$old_owner'"); 

    // and last
    // $pet_buyvalue = 120000;
    // $user_id = 1;

    $new_user_cash = $new_owner->cash;      //checking before updating 
    $new_ownercash = round($new_user_cash - ($pet_buyvalue - $pet_earn));  // user cash         
    $upadte_ownercash = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET cash='$new_ownercash' WHERE id='$user_id'");

    $msg = '<span id="other-info-font">You bought pet yay!</span><br/>';        
}
?>
```

The main problem occurs when two user submit form same time and one have fast net and other dont. some time its cutting **$new_ownercash**. some time only first and second query get updated and third is left with out any changes or (I mean all calculation goes wrong in second and third query) as other user submit form. and i have many user and its a game buy and sale, we are on beta test so still have time to fix it.

It happen when all there user play game same time and it mess up all the things. i am clue ness as i am new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have not given the variable `$old_owner` a value! Ditto with `$user_id`

BTW - Stop using the mysql_ libraries as they are deprecated. Also look into SQL injection - It is dangerous and your script is full of possibilities.

**EDIT**

You are using the same `WHERE` clause in the 2nd and 3rd updates. So running the script "at the same time" will depend how goes first as to how the tables are updated.

Surely `$old_owner` and `$user_id` should be different in the two executions of the script at the same time?

Comment: well i forgot to add them in post but we have them

Comment: @deerox - So what other stuff have you not added? Does the post you give reproduce the problem? (Please take heed to the use of deprecated libraries and SQL injection)

Comment: thanks for replying i have added all missing things. and for i am looking forward for libraries and SQL injection thingy :)

Comment: @deerox - See http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php (the new library). Could use PDO instead

Comment: is there a way ? to join all query in one query?